# Whether or not Java variables are necessary？

Tags: java

- When I learn the programming language, the teacher says that I must initialize, otherwise the empty pointer will make a big mistake.When I set up a `JDBC` connection database, `Intelij IDEA` gives a suggestion that initialization is redundant when the definition of the `ResultSet` variable is initialized to null. Why did not other appear? Sometimes it is also advisable to split a statement into two sentences. An initialization, an assignment.

  ```
  public List<Message> getMesssages() 
  {
      Connection conn = null;
      Statement statement = null;
      ResultSet result = null;
      SQLException ex = null;
      List<Message> messages = null;
      try
      {
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
          statement = conn.createStatement();
          result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM departments");
          messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

          while (result.next()){
              Message message = new Message();
              message.setDept_no(result.getString("dept_no"));
              message.setDept_name(result.getString("dept_name"));
              messages.add(message);
          }

      } catch (SQLException e) {
          ex = e;
      } finally {
          if (statement != null){
              try {
                  statement.close();
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                  if (ex == null){
                      ex = e;
                  }
              }
          }

          if (conn != null){
              try {
                  conn.close();
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                  if (ex == null){
                      ex = e;
                  }
              }
          }

          if (ex != null){
              throw new RuntimeException(ex);
          }
      }

      return messages;
  }
  ```
- I looked at his suggestion but still did not understand

Comment: What is the question here? You should add more clarity here.

Comment: The initialization of `result` is redundant because you initialize it in the only block you use it already.  There's just no way for it to be uninitialized the way your code is written now, you can even move the declaration itself inside your try block.

Comment: And look up try-with-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE tells you, that `ResultSet result` cannot be uninitialized and used in your code. But other variables could be not initialized in some cases, therefore you have to set default value as `null`.

**P.S.** Let me offer another approach of this code. I think this could be more readable and does not have problems with autoclosing resources:

```
public List<Message> getMesssages() throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
         Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM departments");
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

        while (result.next()) {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setDept_no(result.getString("dept_no"));
            message.setDept_name(result.getString("dept_name"));
            messages.add(message);
        }

        return messages;
    }
}
```